# Normalization of One-Particle States for Klein-Gordon Field Quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, dirac-delta-distributions, klein-gordon-equation, normalization

Peskin & Schroeder in their QFT textbook discusses how we may normalize one-particle states $|\textbf{p}\rangle$ for Klein-Gordon field quantization in pages 22-23. The excerpts are given below.

[image]

[image]

I understand the derivations and other technicalities here. Though I have the following questions.

1. I am not sure how Eq. (2.34) can be derived. The formula I am aware of is the following: $$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{\vert f'(x_i) \vert}$$
   where $x_i$ is a simple zero of $f$. Does Eq. (2.34) follow from the above formula? At least, any reference would be highly appreciated where is derivation is discussed.
2. Why do we need to make the inner product $\langle \textbf{p} \vert \textbf{q} \rangle$ Lorentz invariant? Phrased differently, this section didn't discuss how Lorentz invariance comes into play in the formalism developed so far. Then suddenly we want to make the inner product Lorentz invariant.
3. I understand how $E \, \delta(\textbf{p} - \textbf{q})$ is proved to be Lorentz invariant. Then why do they talk about the volume under the Lorentz transformation? How does the volume (also of what) come into the discussion?

> The problem is that volume are not invariant under boosts; ... ... .

4. After Eq. (2.36), it is mentioned why the factor of $2$ is included in Eq. (2.36). I am not quite sure what it has to do with Eq. (2.25) given below. I guess it has something to do with the factor $\sqrt{2\omega_{\textbf{p}}}$. Could you please explain?
   $$\phi(\textbf{x}) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_\textbf{p}}} \left( a_\textbf{p} e^{i\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}} + a_\textbf{p}^\dagger e^{-i\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}} \right).$$

Comment: For the first part, they are just specializing to an $f$ with a single zero.

Comment: ... and redefining: shifting the function by $f(x_0)$, so it is $f(x)-f(x_0)$ which has the zero...

Comment: did you figure out an answer to this question? Actually, can you tell me how they write the first line in page 23?